# How can I catch all errors to same page from web.xml?

Tags: java, web.xml, custom-error-pages, deployment-descriptor

I tried to use

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/error.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

but i dosen't catch 404 errors. How can I catch also 404 etc. errors to that same page ? I want to catch ALL error codes to same error page jsp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add an `<error-code>` tag for that

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

UPDATE:

As per your updated question - you'll have to define EACH error-code individually in the web.xml.

Using `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>` 
will catch the error 500s but not 404s

Comment: I know that, but I want to catch ALL error codes to same page

Comment: @newbie - so you add an <error-page> for each and every error code, all of them pointing at the same page.

Comment: @StephenC:Isn't there any wildcard feature for the same? :/

Comment: According to the Servlet specification, no.  (Check it for yourself.)

Answer (score 3):

I am using this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/exception/sorry.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/security/403</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/security/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat7 (might work on older versions but I didn't check)

add the error pages you want (e.g 404.jsp, general_error.php etc.)

add to web.xml (all first and then specific. adapt it to your code of course):

```
<error-page>
    <location>general_error.php</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>409</error-code>
    <location>error_page.jsp?error=custom_message</location>
</error-page>
```